# I need help to find solution for this query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have MySQL table as follow:

```
id  p_id   c_id

1   11      1

2   11      2

3   11      3

4   12      1

5   12      3

6   13      1

7   13      2
```

I need a query that when `c_id` is 1 and 2, it should return 11 and 13 of `p_id`.

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p_id FROM `Table Name` where c_id in (1,2)
```

which returns: `11, 12, 13`.

but I only need it to return: `11 , 13`.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT p_id FROM `Table Name` where c_id in (1,2) and p_id not in(12) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your query as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.p_id 
FROM table_name AS a
JOIN table_name AS b ON a.p_id=b.p_id
WHERE a.c_id ='1' AND b.c_id ='2';
```

It's a self-join on the table itself

Comment: it`s wrong my friend 
does not work for this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by wrong? Give some more details about the problem.

Comment: https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/BP5m

this my problem and in need answer for this

Comment: your answer does not work for my problem 
https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/BP57

Comment: https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/BP5F
i updated your code but dose not work 
u can see this update in up image

Comment: err I missed it in the where clause it should be as `WHERE a.c_id ='1' AND b.c_id ='2'` previously it was like `WHERE a.c_id ='1' AND a.c_id ='2'`. So your query will be as `WHERE a.cfg_id =1 AND b.cfg_id =2`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.p_id 
FROM table_name AS a
JOIN table_name AS b ON a.p_id=b.p_id
WHERE a.c_id ='1' AND b.c_id ='2';
```

it worked fo me

Comment: How it's different from my answer? By giving the same answer it doesn't add any value to the SO.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is checking for p_ids related to c_is 1 **or** 2. But what you want is 1 **and** 2. You can write this like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.p_id 
FROM table_name as t1
JOIN table_name as t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.c_id = 1 AND t2.c_id = 2;
```

Comment: How it's different from my answer? By giving the same answer it doesn't add any value to the SO.

Comment: It isn't (except for some typos), didn't see your answer when I started writing.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.id
  FROM my_table x
 WHERE other_column IN('a','b')
 GROUP 
    BY x.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: If you have 2 rows with a, it will still return the id

Comment: This is a generic solution